# How to access an Access Database online from a desktop/server?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, server

**Preface**

I created an *Information System* using *Visual Basic* for our office in our school. It uses *OleDb Engine* for an *Access Database*. The database is stored inside the directory or locally inside the application thus making the connection string:

```
"PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = DATA\Base\database.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password =cca"
```

The *Information System* makes the job done on printing, reporting, adding, deleting and editing records.

**What I'm Trying To Achieve**

Now I need to make the database accessible `ONLINE` or `REMOTELY` by making an unused PC be a server instead. This is the overview of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: System to Server to Database]

and the connection string will be like (or *SOMETHING LIKE*)

```
"PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = (address of the server, something like) 10.212.19.3:1234\CCA-SERVER\My Documents\database.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password =cca"
```

telling the system that it will access the database in an address online and on a specific server. Or something like, I will just put the database inside the server and through the internet it will be easily be accessed by the system like a Shared Location inside a network. If so, How can I do it? Where do I begin?

**Question Conclusion**

I'm trying to make a database server. We have a desktop server ready to run. I'm currently digging Google for information and guides how to make it but all I see for now is bumped threads and searching alone won't fill me enough so I decided to ask you guys if you know any

1. Guides.
2. Links to any resources.
3. Tips on where should I start.
4. Links to Tutorials.
5. Tools I'll be needing for the process.

> NOTE: I'll update this if ever somewhere in the internet provides a
>   good guide/tutorial for what I'm trying to achieve and I'll put a link
>   to it incase someone in the future will ask the same question as I
>   did. For now, I'm asking for your help and brief me what I should do step by step.

Thank you.

Comment: Look into web service's. You can create a MySql database and make calls out from .net to a service that will communicate with the database. Dont connect directly use a service.

Comment: I am not sure you can do exactly what you want, but you should be able to share the folder your database is in and access it this way, assuming the Desktop/Server is on the same network as your database. Your connection string would be something like this: `"PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = \\DATABASE_SERVER\DATA\Base\database.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password =cca"` To access that from the Internet you would set up RDP to the spare desktop (which means only one person at a time can access it remotely unless you have an RDS server)

Comment: @SunKnight0 - Yes. Exactly, I need to access it over the internet using my system.

`PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = \\DATABASE_SERVER\DATA\Base\database.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password =cca`

This is for the local network but I'll research about that RDP/RDS, what exactly is that?

Comment: @zaggler - Thank you. Any guides? or links that will get me to do it step by step? or perhaps tell me where should I start? Thank you. I would like to test it out.

Comment: I would need to know what you know first. Do you know how to share a file over a windows network? Do you know how to set up port forwarding on your router/firewall?

Comment: @SunKnight0 - Port-forwarding, Yes. File-sharing, Yes.

Comment: Then all you need to do is set up the spare computer you have to access your database. Then on that computer enable Remote Desktop, set it up with a static IP address or DHCP reservation and forward port 3389 from your public IP address to it. Then any external computer can use Remote Desktop to 'take over' that spare computer. Just make sure any users you set up for remote desktop have strong passwords and basic knowledge on how to keep their passwords secure.

Comment: @SunKnight0 - Thank you for that suggestion. :) Just want to share, I'm working to build an FTP server instead and I will share the database using an FTP server. I'm using FileZilla, if it works then I'll stick to it for now. For locally, the server works and I can access it using ftp://localhost:21 then it will give me the directory listing which is what exactly what I want so my VB.Net app could access the database from there. But I just bumped to a problem that I can't access it externally from the internet, a port-checker/FTP tester said that port 21 is closed but I can access it locally.

Comment: @SunKnight0 - I'll try your suggestion and I'm gonna update you guys what I did to get it working just how I wanted. Thank you so much for your time contributing on where should I start.

Comment: Don't use Access for something like this!  Use SQL Server instead!!
Look at the following link for some ideas of how to create connection strings:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @ryguy7272 - Thank you I read it and it's close to what I need. But a few questions..
1. Is the SQL Server Service will host my 'database.accdb' so it will be accessible over the internet using a connection string?
2. Will I be still using my database or do I need to change my Access Database to an SQL Database?

Because if I have to shift my project's OLEDB oriented functions into an SQL one, it will take some time to re-write everything. But, please answer my main question if I can still use an Access Database over an SQL Server? Thank you.